# Why is my Firebase cloud function code throwing an error when I try and receive data for users email

Tags: javascript, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have been learning how to go about firebase cloud functions and have slowly understood how the HTTPS requests work, however I'm stuck on retrieving data for the users email.

I want to check if the specific email that they enter in the app is already taken in my firebase project, I was going to do it on the client side but learnt that its more secure if I do it through cloud functions.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import { response } from 'express';
admin.initializeApp()

export const getEmail = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
    .then(snapshot => {
        const data = snapshot.data()
        response.send(data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        //Handle error
        console.log(error)
        response.status(500).send(error)
    })
})
```

I keep on receiving an error that the data object does not exist on type 'userRecord'.

Error message (update): Property 'data' does not exist on type 'UserRecord'

Comment: Could you update the post with the error message?

Comment: @jmkmay yep, done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So [admin.auth().getUserByEmail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getUserByEmail) returns a Promise containing non-null [UserRecord](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord).

`UserRecord` doesn't appear to have a method `data()`. If you want to get the JSON representation of this `UserRecord`, use:

`const data = snapshot.toJSON()`

If you only need to access the email, use:

`const data = snapshot.email`

Comment: Thank you! Silly mistake

Comment: That seems like a linting warning. Are you able to deploy it with that message or is it preventing you from doing so?

Comment: I got it to deploy, I forgot to save it lol, just trying to work out how to call the function and pass the email parameter with it in Swift